# TargetParameterCountException with Invoke()

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, lambda, extension-methods

I am trying to update a control, but keep getting a cross threading exception error (note: cross-threading exception error only occurs when debugging with VS, works fine when I just run the .exe).  So I goggle that, and arrive at the Invoke method.  Now I am getting this error.

I am trying to use the extension method:

```
    public static void Invoke<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : Control
    {
        if (c.InvokeRequired)
            c.TopLevelControl.Invoke(action);
        else
            action(c);
    }
```

to update a progressbar.  Using the below code.

```
pb.TextLabel.Invoke(c => c.Text = "Copying " + Path.GetFileName(this.mp2File));
```

but I keep getting the following error:

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147352562   Message=Parameter count mismatch.
>   Source=System.Windows.Forms   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
>          at AV_Processor.Extensions.Invoke[T](T c, Action`1 action)
>          at AV_Processor.FormProcessor.Copy(Int32 _i)
>          at AV_Processor.FormProcessor.ProcessTable(Int32 pState)
>          at AV_Processor.FormProcessor.buttonProcess_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>          at AV_Interface.FormInterface.buttonSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\madeup\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\madeup\madeup\AV-Interface\FormInterface.cs:line 756
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at AV_Interface.FormInterface.Main() in C:\Users\donkeykong\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\blahblah
>   Source Controlled\bababa\sosdfg\FormInterface.cs:line 362
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

I have it set to compile to All CPU, but the cross thread exception error only occurs when I run it in the VS debugger.  How can I run the above code in the debugger ?

Comment: Why don't you invoke to control itself? `c.Invoke(action)`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it.  Is there any issues with not checking if an invoke is required and just invoking stuff by default ?

Comment: Keep `if(c.InvokeRequired)` if you can not guarantee, what it will be called from same UI thread. And it should be safe to invoke anything even if you don't need it, though it is not efficient.

Comment: It bombs out if I use c.Invoke(action)

Comment: With or without `if(c.InvokeRequired)` ? How does the *bomb* looks like? I know what for events you have to also check if handle is created (see [IsHandleCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated.aspx)). Without handle you can't invoke yet or do anything.

Comment: You are correct, it was a handle error.